# How to recover a password hint from a drive encrypted with Disk Utility?

Tags: macos, encryption, aes

I encrypted a drive with Disk Utility on macOS and set a password hint. I saved the password in the keychain and my computer was stolen. Unfortunately, my most recent backup is inside this encrypted drive. The answers on [this Ask Different thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299558/how-do-i-get-the-password-hint-for-an-encrypted-disk) did not work for me. I use different passwords every time and rely on the hints to remember them.

Here is the ouptut of `diskutil coreStorage list`:

```
$diskutil coreStorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group B2800A76-F42F-40FF-84BB-2511E928BF29
    =========================================================
    Name:         Time Machine Encryped
    Status:       Online
    Size:         239712407552 B (239.7 GB)
    Free Space:   16318464 B (16.3 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 554CBE3D-5212-4FF8-A7A6-A95FCAA7B511
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     239712407552 B (239.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 422F58D5-FF65-472A-8942-1F4E4F3CA83A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Locked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 2930C7CC-4EE4-43AB-B1FB-81756A1CC0E5
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  -none-
            Status:                Locked
            Size (Total):          239343763456 B (239.3 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Time Machine Encryped
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Note that at the bottom it says `Content Hint: Apple_HFS`. Note also that a bash command such as `diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume [GUID] -passphrase [pass]` takes 1-2 seconds to run and does not try to decrypt 240 GB, so I guess that the password is stored somewhere in this hierarchy.

If I knew the password hint, I would remember the password. How can I recover the password hint?

Comment: Why didn't you post the question on Ask Different?

Comment: Two reasons: the question would be duplicate on Ask Different and I am looking for a software solution, since Apple products may not work.

Comment: You want to write your own program to recover the password hint?

Comment: Yes, I wonder if such a program exists.

Comment: Is this of anyhelp?
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/forgot-your-mac-password-3-ways-to-unlock-startup-disks-encrypted-with-filevault/

Comment: The encryption type is AES-XTS, so it could have been done by FileVault. Solution 1 in that post assumes that the drive encrypted is the boot disk with a recovery key, not an external one like I have. Solution 2 has a useful command `diskutil corestorage unlockVolume UUID -passphrase recoveryKey` that I tried previously. Solution 3 "requires a copy of the FileVaultMaster.keychain file ... created ... prior to the password being lost".